# Problems with my Crypter

Tags: python, encryption

I tried to make a basic crypter using python that used the [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) cipher to make an indecipherable message
(Yes, I know, randint isn't actually random and it's crap for security.)

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

choose = input("Encrypt or Decrypt?")
if choose == 'encrypt':
    alphabet = "afqtEVnUGAYIBMTpXsrjlgFJNicSPOKoLDWzdCyukxeRmvbhwHQZ1234567890_?.,;:!&*कखगघङचछजझञटठडढणतथदधनपफबभमक़"

    crypt_string = ""
    crypted_string = []
    crypt_con = False
    enc_key = []
    while crypt_con == False:
        print('Please enter a string to be encrypted.')
        crypt_string_in = input('letters and numbers only. Use underscore instead of space.')
        crypt_string = crypt_string_in
        crypt_con = True
    print ("Crypting...")
    sleep(3)
    for let in crypt_string:
        key = randint(0,27)
        letpos = alphabet.index(let)
        letter = alphabet[letpos + key]
        crypted_string.append(letter)
        enc_key.append(key)

    print ("Your string:" + ''.join(crypted_string))
    print ("The encryption key:" + ''.join(str(enc_key)))
    input ('Press ENTER to exit.')

elif choose == 'decrypt':
    alphabet = "afqtEVnUGAYIBMTpXsrjlgFJNicSPOKoLDWzdCyukxeRmvbhwHQZ1234567890_?.,;:!&*कखगघङचछजझञटठडढणतथदधनपफबभमक़"
    print ('Input the string.')
    crypted_str = input('') 
    print ('And the key?')
    cryptlist = []
    cryptkey_in = input('')
    cryptkey = eval(cryptkey_in)
    cryptlist.append(cryptkey)
    print (cryptlist)
    decrypted_str = []
    for let in crypted_str:
        letpos = alphabet.index(let)
        letkeypos = cryptlist[0][crypted_str.index(let)]
        print (letkeypos)
        correctlet = alphabet[letpos - letkeypos]
        print (correctlet)
        decrypted_str.append(correctlet)
    print ("".join(decrypted_str))
```

However, when I encrypt and then decrypt something with the same key, it becomes incoherent. The alphabet is the same for both, and the Hindi is a placeholder to stop index errors.

Let's go through using this:

*Encrypt or Decrypt?*

**Encrypt**

*Please enter a string to be encrypted.
letters and numbers only. Use underscore instead of space.*

**Hello_Bob.I_trust_you_are_doing_very_well.**

*Your string:&6Wxyटzd.ञCडUk?yBण65;.pi?ज73xAW?*ZC0ग3wLlठ
The encryption key:[20, 15, 14, 21, 7, 19, 23, 5, 18, 16, 26, 21, 4, 22, 24, 21, 9, 23, 19, 25, 27, 2, 15, 7, 21, 16, 22, 23, 16, 3, 13, 1, 25, 9, 19, 23, 11, 6, 6, 12, 0, 18]*

I copied this into Notepad and reopened the file.

*Encrypt or Decrypt?*

**Decrypt**

*Input the string.*

**&6Wxyटzd.ञCडUk?yBण65;.pi?ज73xAW?*ZC0ग3wLlठ**

*And the key?*

**[20, 15, 14, 21, 7, 19, 23, 5, 18, 16, 26, 21, 4, 22, 24, 21, 9, 23, 19, 25, 27, 2, 15, 7, 21, 16, 22, 23, 16, 3, 13, 1, 25, 9, 19, 23, 11, 6, 6, 12, 0, 18]**

*H
15
e
14
l
21
l
7
o
19
_
23
B
5
o
18
b
16
.
26
I
21
_
4
t
22
r
24
u
7
o
9
t
23
_
15
e
25
o
27
u
18
b
15
a
7
r
24
u
16
_
22
d
23
o
21
l
3
n
14
l
24
u
25
v
9
e
26
I
23
y
11
_
23
o
6
e
12
l
0
l
18
.
Hello_Bob.I_truot_eoubaru_dolnluveIy_oell.*

As you can see, it went pretty well until the word "trust."

I'm not sure what is wrong with my program. When I tested it on shorter strings, it produced the desired effect. Does it have to do with the punctuation's effect on the string?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but personally I would call the variables `plain_str` and `cipher_str` rather than `crypt_str` and `crypted_str` (or even just `plain` and `cipher`).  (plain text and cipher text are the normal terms, and having variable names that are so similar will complicate bug finding).

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is this:

```
letkeypos = cryptlist[0][crypted_str.index(let)]
```

The part `crypted_str.index(let)` will not return the position of your actuall letter but the first occurence of the same letter in the string `crypted_str`. Thus you will access the wrong key element.

To iterate over a string while knowing the element's index, you might use this:

```
for idx,val in enumerate("abcdef"):
    print idx
    print val
```

Also, you should not do cryptography on readable strings but on binary level instead. And also look at how the modulo operator might help you using your
alphabet workaraound.

---

As a general note: Your code looks like you are new to programming, that's cool, keep trying! However, Cryptography and Security in general are very tricky topics. Never use something like this in real world applications. But for fun it's OK!

Comment: Yeah, I said in the post that randint was useless for cryptography. But seriously, thanks for the help. That never occured to me.

Comment: Also, I think the alphabet workaround is pretty fine as is. Eve would be really confused if they saw a whole load of Devanagari script.

Comment: Glad I could help :) If my answer solves your question you should accept the answer ;-)